# Как на css сделать свечение внутри блока?

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы было белое свечение внутри синего блока. Как такое реализовать на CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так же при помощи  `background: radial-gradient(circle)`

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, hsl(210,55%,85%), hsl(210,55%,55%))
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Так, например...

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 130px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```